# CORS rejection in Disqus Authentication

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, disqus

I'm trying to use Disqus OAuth2 authentication. This is what I did:

1: Created a disqus application and set `http://myweb/login` as callback uri and `myweb` in the Domain textarea (Domains linked to your public key (for referral checks)).

2: Tried to make XHR GET request on `disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/authorize` from `http://myweb/somepage`. CORS error appears.

I solved it by calling

```
window.open("https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/authorize/?
client_id="+id+"&scope=read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://myweb/login",
"_blank");
```

Where `id` is th ID of my application. This works, I get the `code` response in the URL.

3: Now I need to POST to retrieve the access token. CORS error again. I tried to create and submit form and the server response is OK.

The errors are:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://disqus.com/api/oauth/2.0/authorize/?
client_id=...&redirect_uri=http://myweb/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://myweb' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I feel that I am doing something wrong, that the disqus OAuth2 server should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for my application or something. So how to avoid the CORS errors in HTTP requests?

I don't want to use PHP or jQuery to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Disqus OAuth implementation is a server-side only, which is why your request is being rejected. Even if you could make the request client-side, you would be exposing your API secret key, which wouldn't be good.

You would have to use PHP or another server-side language to make the request for the access token, I'm afraid.

Comment: OK, I could make a XHR to my PHP server which can nagotiate the authentication via CURL and send back the result. Good point, thanks.